# Python Function Decorator Puzzle

Tags: python, decorator

I recently leant the subject of python decorators, and found something strange for the below two different programs:

Example1:

```
def deco(func):
    def inner():
        print("Running inner")
    return func

@deco
def target():
    print("Running target")

def main():
    print("Running main()")
    target()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example2:

```
def deco(func):
    print("Running inner")
    return func

@deco
def target():
    print("Running target")

def main():
    print("Running main()")
    target()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When running Example1 and Example2, it will get 2 different results:

```
Running main()
Running target
```

in Example1, and

```
Running inner
Running main()
Running target
```

in Example2.

It seems "Running inner" was lost in Example1. Why?

Comment: Didn't you mix up the output for example 1 and example 2?

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes. Already modified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running Example 2 will give that result because `deco` is executed at definition time, and in that example it prints `inner` immediately.

Example 1 won't print inner because you never do anything with the `inner` func. Your decorator there should be returning `inner`, not `func`; and `inner` itself should call func:

```
def deco(func):
    def inner():
        print("Running inner")
        func()
    return inner   # note change here
```

When you do this, you will get this result:

```
Running main()
Running inner
Running target
```

which is what you would expect from a decorator.

Comment: you mean because I returned the func itself, so the inner function didn't execute in Example1. Right?

Comment: Yes; nothing is calling it.